# How to change NA values into specific values based on another variable?

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse

My dataset looks like this:

```
ID      QA    QB     QC   QD   QE
TO_12    1    2      NA    3    2
TO_13    1    2      NA    3    2
TO_14    1    2      NA    3    2
BO_15    1    2      2     NA   NA
BO_16    1    2      2     NA   NA
BO_17    1    2      2     NA   NA
```

I want to remove all rows that have `NA` values after the first three columns (e.g., rows starting with `'BO'` and want to replace `NA` values in `QC` with `2` so that it looks like this:

```
ID      QA    QB     QC   QD  QE
TO_12    1    2      2    3    2
TO_13    1    2      2    3    2
TO_14    1    2      2    3    2
```

I'd highly appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mutate` together with `is_else` to replace the `NA` values in column `QC`. Then you can drop the rows with `NA` using `drop_na`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
      ~ID, ~QA,  ~QB,   ~QC, ~QD, ~QE,
  "TO_12",   1,    2,    NA,   3,   2,
  "TO_13",   1,    2,    NA,   3,   2,
  "TO_14",   1,    2,    NA,   3,   2,
  "BO_15",   1,    2,     2,  NA,  NA,
  "BO_16",   1,    2,     2,  NA,  NA,
  "BO_17",   1,    2,     2,  NA,  NA
)

df %>% 
  mutate(QC = if_else(is.na(QC), 2, QC)) %>%  # replaces NAs in QC with 2
  drop_na(QD:QE) # drops every row where NA is in cols QD to QE
```

The output then is:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  ID       QA    QB    QC    QD    QE
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 TO_12     1     2     2     3     2
2 TO_13     1     2     2     3     2
3 TO_14     1     2     2     3     2
```